# Downloading millions of files from azure blob container using csv of the file paths python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azcopy

I am trying to find out a faster way to download millions of files from azure blob container. The container has more than 200 million files. I’m trying to download 3 million files. The paths of the files are not organised well. I have a csv of the file paths I need to download. Here’s what I tried:

1. Tried forming SAS token for each file and download it using multithreading(requests library) in python.
2. Tried downloading the files directly using azure storage blob package using python(I tried to parallelise this as well but for some reason requests was so much faster than the python sdk of azure blob).

Is there any other better way to download the files quickly?

Note: I am trying to download it from inside a virtual machine, so the network speed won’t be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions, which you can consider:

1. Ensure that the Azure VM, is in *same region* (Location) as that of Azure Storage. This will give a better network performance. Also make sure that the VM has better configuration.
2. Ensure that you are using the updated [Storage Python SDK package libraries](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/12.15.0/).
3. Ensure that you have set the optimal value for [max_concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-download-blob). This setting is for the number of parallel connections with which to download.
4. You can check the metrics for the Azure Storage account and check latency metrics to isolate which factor is contributing to the latency. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-latency#about-azure-storage-latency).
5. `get_blob_to_path` method: This method is the fastest way to download a blob to a local file. This method downloads the blob in chunks, which can improve performance. You can also specify the number of parallel download threads to use, which can further improve performance.
6. `get_blob_to_bytes` method: This method is similar to the get_blob_to_path method, but it downloads the blob to a byte array instead of a local file. This method can be useful if you need to process the blob data in memory. Also has automatic chunking.
7. `get_blob_to_stream` method: This method is similar to the get_blob_to_path method, but it downloads the blob to a stream instead of a local file and has automatic chunking with progress notifications. This method can be useful if you need to process the blob data in real-time.

Refer the Sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-python#download-a-blob-in-chunks). More Information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-download-blob). Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand how those suggestions help increase a big file's download speed. I could not find which items in the list refer to parallelizing the download of multiple small files.